# How to display a newly created record

Tags: apex, trigger

On pick list value change I want to created a new record on different object and want to redirect on the new record which is created.

How can I implement it?

Comment: I suggest you to use process builder to implement it.

Comment: In process builder how can I redirect to the new record. Can you guide me on that ?

Comment: Right Sumit, you can not redirect to the newly created record using process builder.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily achieve it using apex:actionSupport

Code snippet for actionSupport:

```
<apex:page controller="RedirectController">
    <apex:form>
    <apex:selectList id="chooseColor" value="{!string}" size="1">
        <apex:selectOption itemValue="red" itemLabel="Red"/>
        <apex:selectOption itemValue="white" itemLabel="White"/>
        <apex:selectOption itemValue="blue" itemLabel="Blue"/>
        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!pageRedirect}" rerender=""/>
    </apex:selectList> 
</apex:form>
```

Controller:

```
public class RedirectController {

    public PageReference pageRedirect(){
        //insert the object 
        PageReference pg = new PageReference('/' + Pass_the_Id_of_Object_created);
        pg.setRedirect(true);
        return pg ;
    }
}
```

NOTE: This code snippet is not exact. For more details refer [Apex action support](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionSupport.htm?search_text=apex:act)

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: If the abpve answer addressed your problem, you can accept it by clicking on the check mark/tick to the left of the answer, turning it green and useful